# Compile time calculation of next item in enum?

Tags: c++, templates

For example, I have an enum

```
enum Option
{
   A = 0, B = 1, C = 2
};
```

and I want to get its compile time next of result, i.e. `nextOf<A> = B, nextOf<B> = C, nextOf<C> = A`, how do I implement it?

Comment: Does `myEnum+1` not work for you?

Comment: do you want to implement a state machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `constexpr` to write a compile time function.

```
#include <iostream>

enum Option
{
   A = 0, B = 1, C = 2
};

constexpr Option nextOf(const Option option){
  switch (option){
    case A: return B;
    case B: return C;
  }
  return A;
}

int main (){
  constexpr Option next = nextOf(A);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach could be using partial specializations of a structure.
As an example:

```
enum Option { A = 0, B = 1, C = 2 };

template<Option>
struct next;

template<> struct next<A> { static constexpr Option value = B; };
template<> struct next<B> { static constexpr Option value = C; };
template<> struct next<C> { static constexpr Option value = A; };

template<Option O>
constexpr Option next_v = next<O>::value;

int main (){
    constexpr Option next = next_v<A>;
    static_assert(next_v<B> == C, "!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `enum`s are integers in disguise, you can simply define

```
contexpr Option next(Option u)
{
   return (Option(int(u)+1);
}
```

Or course this let next(C) as undefined behavior. The alternative can be a %3 result, so that next(C) = A (a wrap-aroud arithmetic typical on int-s)

```
   return (Option((int(u)+1)%3);
```

or a filter on input, throwing an exception, but that will make the fucntion no more `consterxpr`.